# Cast to a control using the control name as a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have several textfields (and labels) in my XIB and at some point in my application I build dynamicaly a string which contains a control name (i.e. one of the textfields).
How can I refer to the actual textfield using the string I created that holds the name of the textfield.

For example, I have txt1 , txt2, txt3, txt4 as UITextFields
and i have a string (str) that contains one of the fields above names (str ="txt3")
then i want to change the content of the uitextfield txt3 since str have "txt3"
at this point.

How do I cast from the string to the actual control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `UITextField`s all have a backing property then you can use KVC to get a reference to the control and then you just use it as normal.

```
NSString *str = @"txt1";
UITextField *myTextField = [self valueForKey:str];
myTextField.text = @"what ever you want to update to";
```

### Side note

Although you have not mentioned the source of `str` @JefferyThomas raises a very valid point about not trusting use input that has not been validated.

Comment: I think it's important to note may not be such a good idea. At least, you will want to rigorously scrub any user input before you start executing code like this.

Comment: I should have clarified, no user involvment here, the application build the str field according to some logic. no user input for that field.  Thanks for your comment it worked as i wanted.!

Comment: If this solved your problem then just hit the accept answer button, so people know what the solution is.

Comment: Hi Paul, I don't see any 'accept answer' button only 'was it useful to you' which I clicked Yes. what am i missing?

Comment: @StkStocki - this confused me, too when I started using SO.  To accept an answer, click the checkbox that appears underneath the large number (of up votes) at the upper left of the answer.